# How do I specify which db laravel should use for a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have 2 models, `Asset` & `Event`. The db for `Asset` is located on `server 1` and the db for `Event` is located on `server 2`.

Asset and Event have a many to many relationship define in each model as below

**\app\Models\Asset.php**

```
class Asset extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $connection = 'server1';
protected $table = 'assetstable'; 
protected $primaryKey = 'assetid';

public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class)->using(AssetEvent::class);
}
}
```

**\app\Models\Event.php**

```
class Event extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'events';

public function assets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Asset::class)->using(AssetEvent::class);
}
}
```

When I attempted to access an `Asset` from the `Event` with something like `$event = Event::where('id', $event_id)->with('assets')->get();` I get an error saying the pivot table `asset_event` can not be found. The reason it can't be found is it is looking for it on `server 1` . The `asset_event` table is located on `server 2`.

I need to be able to specify which server the pivot table is located on, but I can't seem to find how to do this.

TLDR: How do I tell laravel where a particular pivot table is located.

--Update based on comment-- 
I've now added a pivot model as below but I get the same error

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class assetevent extends Pivot
{
use HasFactory;

public $incrementing = true;

protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $table = 'asset_event'; 

}
```

Comment: Have you defined a pivot model with a `$connection` property?

Comment: @miken32 I had not, I didn't realise that was a "thing", quite new to this. I have now including adding `->using(AssetEvent::class);` to both my models. Still same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem.

I have fixed it only setting connection name directly in the relation.

Such as:

```
public function discounts(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->setConnection('mysql')->belongsToMany(Discount::class);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pro1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_2=mysql
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=pro2
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=
```

in config/database.php

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

in Model

`protected $connection = 'mysql1';` or `protected $connection = 'mysql2';`

Comment: I have this for access the two models and I can access both models but if I want to access via a relationship it needs a pivot table and unless I place the pivot table on server 1 with the asset table it doesn't work. I need the pivot table to be on server 2